# passing this.value from javascript insertCell HTML input markup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a javascript function that creates a table and inserts a cell with `insertCell(0);`

Inside the cell is an html form input that calls another function onKeyUp that i pass 4 parameters to. The last parameter is the value of the input `this.value`. This value is always passed as undefined.  Is there a way to get that value when the user updates the qty?

I can't use an ID selector as the tr is created every time an item is added to the cart.

I'm posting the whole function, but this is the problem line.

This doesn't work...

```
cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' onKeyUp='updateQty("+posItem.id+",\""+posItem.color+"\",\""+posItem.size+"\","+this.value+")' name='qty' value='"+posItem.qty+"' class='textfield'/>";
```

here is the whole function

```
function addToPosCart(posItem) {

    posCart.push(posItem);

    var table=document.getElementById("cart_table");

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    tr.className = 'row';
    tr.setAttribute('row_id',posItem.id);
    tr.setAttribute('color',posItem.color);

    var totalPrice = posItem.price * posItem.qty;

    var cell1=tr.insertCell(0);
    var cell2=tr.insertCell(1);
    var cell3=tr.insertCell(2);
    var cell4=tr.insertCell(3);
    var cell5=tr.insertCell(4);
    var cell6=tr.insertCell(5);
    var cell7=tr.insertCell(6);

    cell1.innerHTML="<input type='text' onKeyUp='updateQty("+posItem.id+",\""+posItem.color+"\",\""+posItem.size+"\","+this.value+")' name='qty' value='"+posItem.qty+"' style='width:30px' class='textfield input_qty'/>";
    cell2.innerHTML="<span style='font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;'>"+posItem.name+"</span><br>"+posItem.color +" "+posItem.size;
    cell3.innerHTML="$"+posItem.price.toFixed(2);
    cell4.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='dis_dollars' value='"+posItem.disDollars+"' style='width:30px' class='textfield'/>";
    cell5.innerHTML="<input type='text' name='dis_percent' value='"+posItem.disPercent+"' style='width:30px' class='textfield'/>";
    cell6.innerHTML="$"+totalPrice.toFixed(2);
    cell7.innerHTML="<a onclick='deleteItem(this.rowid)' style='height:22px;width:23px;padding:1px 0 0 0px;'class='button_black'>&#10060;</a>";

    updateTotals();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' onKeyUp='updateQty(" + posItem.id + ",\"" + posItem.color + "\",\"" + posItem.size + "\",this.value)' name='qty' value='" + posItem.qty + "' style='width:30px' class='textfield input_qty'/>";
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LZm6e/)

Comment: Wow, I could have sworn I tried that, as well as every other combo I could concoct.  It works great, thanks, been stuck on that for hours!!!